# How to convert view in base64 image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image-processing

Hello i have one view in which i can draw lines.
Now i want convert it into base64 image, so how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);    
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewimage);
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

where view is the view where lines are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, for converting NSData into Base64 string you need use a third party code. I advise you to use Base64 category written by Math Gallagher wich i've used with success. This is the link: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html